# Bibtex: two months with dates

Tags: bibtex

I would like to insert the dates of a conference into my bibtex-file. The conference took place in the period 29. november and 2. december. I tried the following, but with a not very satisfactory result:

```
month=nov#{29--2}#dec
```

Can someone help me to get proper dates?

Comment: The `month` field doesn't refer to the date when the conference took place, but to the month in which the proceedings were published.

Comment: You can use `month={29 }#nov#{--2 }#dec`, but it's misusing the field.

Comment: The document I have does not contain any information what kind of paper it is. I have found the citation of it in another paper like follows:


Zheng, H., Xie, L. and Zhang, L.Z. (2005) ‘Electricity price 
forecasting based on GARCH model in deregulated market’, 
The 7th International Power Engineering Conference, 29 
Nov.-2 Dec. 2005.

Comment: The date should be part of the conference title.

Comment: You mean like: " The 7th International Power Engineering Conference taking place on 29 Nov.-2 Dec. 2005"?

Comment: For conference papers there is an obligatory field "booktitle", until now I used the conference name as booktitle (although not sure if it is correct), but a booktitle with a date?

Answer (score 3):

The `month` field should store the month when the book or journal number was published, which is almost surely not the date the conference took place.

That date interval is part of the title of the book; with scholar.google.com I got this BibTeX entry

```
@inproceedings{hua2005electricity,
  title={Electricity price forecasting based on GARCH model in deregulated market},
  author={Hua, Zheng and Li, Xie and Li-zi, Zhang},
  booktitle={Power Engineering Conference, 2005. IPEC 2005. The 7th International},
  pages={1--410},
  year={2005},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

that's how IEEE advertises it, see [this link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1627232).

You *might* add

```
month={29 }#nov#{--2 }#dec
```

or more simply

```
month={29~Nov.--2~Dec.}
```

but it would be misusing the field.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](http://web.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/biberrors.html), you can use the `month` field:

```
month = "29~" # nov # "--" # "2~" # dec
```

The cardinal (`#`) is the BibTeX concatenate operator.

Comment: This gives month numbers, not names.

Comment: @vonbrand I think that is determined by your bib style. Here, the three-letter abbreviations (nov, dec) are recognized by bibtex as months and then it uses your bib style to print them out consistently in whatever format you would like to. This is also explained in the link provided in my answer.