# BibTeX and biber quarterly journals

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, date

I need to add a quarterly journal to my references.  In these cases issues cover three months such as "January-March".

I am aware of the question [Bibtex: two months with dates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179330/bibtex-two-months-with-dates), however it seems that the solutions do not work with biber.

How to manage quarterly journals with biber? Do we have solutions working with  both biber and BibTeX?

### Edit

Note that in the linked question, they mention the `month` field. However, I only would like to know which is a proper entry for a quarterly journal in a `.bib` file, whether involving the `month` field or not.

When I can choose, I use BibLaTeX with `biber`, but some journals require `bibtex` and it would be nice if I could find a correct way to set the quarterly journal entry in the `.bib` file in such a way that it work for both `biber` and `bibtex`.

Comment: Your question is not all that clear, I'm afraid. Please clarify which field is supposed to be used to store the `"January--March"` piece of information. The `month` or `number` field, or some other field?

Comment: `biblatex`'s `date` fields expect ISO 8601 input and will produce output that may not be exactly what you want anyway. Pretty much the only valid input for "January-March 2019" would be `date = {2019-10/2019-03},`. You could put the `January-March` into the `issue` field, or into `number` if you feel really adventurous.

Comment: @mico: hopefully the edit meets your requirements

Comment: Is there something stopping you from setting the month field to, say,: `month = "Jan.--Mar.` or `month = "Apr.--June"`?

Comment: @Mico: With biber I get the warning: `month field 'Apr.--June' ... is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.`. In this regard `date={2019-04/2019-06}`, suggested by @moewe, works better.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is going to be a solution that works properly for all BibTeX styles (that's how I interpret the desideratum that the solution is supposed to work with BIbTeX) and `biblatex` (for which Biber is the preferred backend). There is too much variety with respect to small details like this between different `.bst` files and `biblatex`.

---

For most BibTeX styles (ab)using the `month` field as shown in [Bibtex: two months with dates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179330/35864) is pretty much the only option.

For `biblatex` the situation is a bit different since `month` is supposed to only hold an integer between 1 and 12.

---

If the journal has volume and issue numbers, I would not bother with the months too much. The `volume` and `number` fields will be enough to properly identify the source.

Take the article https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006 in the *Reviews of Modern Physics* for example. It was published in Volume 91, number 2 (April-June 2019). The following output appears to be sufficiently detailed to me.

> Catalina Curceanu et al. ‘The modern era of light kaonic atom experiments’. In: *Rev. Mod. Phys.* 91.2, 025006 (2019). doi: [10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006).

---

Anyway, if you are OK with what `biblatex` makes of the date range, you can give the range April-June 2019 in ISO 8601 format in the date field: `date = {2019-04/2019-06}`. This would be my preferred course of action if the months are seen as important for the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{curceanu,
  title   = {The modern era of light kaonic atom experiments},
  author  = {Curceanu, Catalina and Guaraldo, Carlo
             and Iliescu, Mihail and Cargnelli, Michael
             and Hayano, Ryugo and Marton, Johann and Zmeskal, Johann
             and Ishiwatari, Tomoichi and Iwasaki, Masa
             and Okada, Shinji and Sirghi, Diana Laura
             and Tatsuno, Hideyuki},
  journal = {Rev. Mod. Phys.},
  volume  = {91},
  number  = {2},
  eid     = {025006},
  date    = {2019-04/2019-06},
  doi     = {10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,curceanu}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Catalina Curceanu et al. ‘The modern era of light kaonic atom experiments’. In: Rev. Mod. Phys. 91.2, 025006 (Apr.–June 2019). doi: 10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006.]

In this case the output is looks pretty like the output the journal would suggest, but this can not be guaranteed in general, since the date format is left for `biblatex` to decide. With a different setting you might see "04/2019-06/2019" instead.

---

If you want a 'fixed' output, you'd probably put the `April--June` into the `issue` field. `issue` can be used for journal subdivisions that go with the `year`/`date` instead of subdivisions that go with `volume` (where `number` would be the right choice).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{curceanu,
  title   = {The modern era of light kaonic atom experiments},
  author  = {Curceanu, Catalina and Guaraldo, Carlo
             and Iliescu, Mihail and Cargnelli, Michael
             and Hayano, Ryugo and Marton, Johann and Zmeskal, Johann
             and Ishiwatari, Tomoichi and Iwasaki, Masa
             and Okada, Shinji and Sirghi, Diana Laura
             and Tatsuno, Hideyuki},
  journal = {Rev. Mod. Phys.},
  volume  = {91},
  number  = {2},
  eid     = {025006},
  date    = {2019},
  issue   = {April--June},
  doi     = {10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,curceanu}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Catalina Curceanu et al. ‘The modern era of light kaonic atom experiments’. In: Rev. Mod. Phys. 91.2, 025006 (April–June 2019). doi: 10.1103/RevModPhys.91.025006.]

---

You shouldn't try and out the month range into the `month` field with Biber, since `month` is supposed to be an integer (this is needed for sorting purposes).